# jQuery + loop not working in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following script, which I can't seem to get to work in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/wq6Cc/17/):

I can't see why this is not working?

```
var $widget = $("<div class='widget widget_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $(".column_" + j );
$("<div class='widget_header widget_header_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $widget );
$("<div class='widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $widget );
$("<div class='widget_content widget_content_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $widget );
$("<div class='widget_footer widget_footer_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $widget );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an error in your script. You forgot the closing bracket in the following line:

```
var $widget =                   // --------------------------------------v
    $("<div class='widget widget_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $(".column_" + j) );
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wq6Cc/18/

Answer (score 1):

you have to change this

```
var $widget = $("<div class='widget widget_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $(".column_" + j );
```

to

```
  var $widget = $("<div class='widget widget_" + i + "'>").appendTo( $(".column_" + j ) );
```

and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your question, with a bit of channing your code could be much cleaner.

```
$('#divMain').empty()
    .append( $('<div>').addClass('column column_1') )
    .append( $('<div>').addClass('column column_2') )
    .append( $('<div>').addClass('column column_3') );

$('.column').sortable({
    tolerance   : 'pointer',
    connectWith : '.column'
});

for (var j = 1, i; j <= 3; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        $('<div>').addClass('widget widget_' + i)
            .append( $('<div>').addClass('widget_header widget_header_' + i) )
            .append( $('<div>').addClass('widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_' + i) )
            .append( $('<div>').addClass('widget_content widget_content_' + i) )
            .append( $('<div>').addClass('widget_footer widget_footer_' + i) )
            .appendTo('.column_' + j);
    }
}
```